In TypeScript, how do you implement a function interface that has other, normal functions?
This is very similar to this question: Is it possible to implement a function interface in TypeScript?
This is the highest voted answer:
interface FunctionInterface {
    (s: string): boolean;
}

const f: FunctionInterface = s => true;
const b: boolean = f('someString');

That works when the function interface is a single function, but what is the syntax to implement this when FunctionInterface has multiple properties like this (Playground link):
interface FunctionInterface {
    (s: string): boolean;
    foo: () => void;
}
const f: FunctionInterface = s => true; // Property 'foo' is missing in type '(s: string) => true' but required in type 'FunctionInterface'.

const b: boolean = f('someString');

This is my attempt (Playground link) but it doesn't come close to compiling:
interface FunctionInterface {
    (s: string): boolean;
    foo: () => void;
}
const f: FunctionInterface = {
  (): s => true;
  foo: () => {};
};

const b: boolean = f('someString');


You can do it like this or with Object.assign(); see linked q/a above for more information.

@jcalz thank you! When I look at that answer it seems like the syntax needs to be multi-line?

@jcalz nm, that was explicitly mentioned by you in the other answer: "Since TypeScript 3.1, and as implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#26368, you've been allowed to add properties to functions after their declarations without running into compiler warnings. So you can make a DescribableFunction relatively straightfowardly." Thanks again
